# Site description has a typo when sharing a question on Facebook

Tags: bug, status-declined

It was brought up [in our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6390843#6390843) that when sharing a message on facebook, there's a missing space in the site description ("forengineers"):

[image: forengineers]

I don't believe I can edit this description as a mod. Could someone from StackExchange please correct this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug on Facebook's end, they're stripping a space that appears before the bold text in this sidebar.

[image]

It is there in our markup as served to Facebook.

Comment: That is a bummer :/

Comment: Ah well. Thanks all the same!